# Is it possible to get the actual start time and end time for a MS Teams meeting?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I've already built a proof-of-concept app in the MS teams, got it connected, got the graph and all the events and online meeting sorted out. So here's the thing right now is how can I get the actual time that I joined that specific meeting/event and the actual time that I left not the one that was set by an initiator because sometimes there are times that a meeting might be extended.

I've already tried looking at the graph api on the Online Meetings > Attendance report, it seems firing that API doesn't even returning me a data from that meeting/event. It was empty. Do we need something on this? I was hoping that I would be able to get an attendance report data based on the meetingId that i've provided. Any insights would be appreciated on this.

I tried this approach based on the image below
[image]

Comment: You can use attendanceRecords Graph API. This includes List of time periods between joining and leaving a meeting. The records are available only after the online meeting ends. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attendancerecord-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Comment: Hi @Meghana-MSFT, i've updated my post about additional information, that's the value that i'm getting at after executing that attendanceReport to get the report id but it's empty

Comment: It is working fine. We created an online meeting using following API - https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2BHO.png. We joined the meeting and then called List meetingAttendanceReports API once the meeting has ended. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv9Vi.png